# Is there a difference between [^[:print:]] and [[:cntrl:]]

Tags: python, regex

Trying to determine if there is a functional difference between the POSIX character groups named above, or more specifically, the following two patterns:

```
r'[^[\x20-\x7E]]'  # Match All non-printable
r'[\x00-\x1F\x7F]'  # Match control characters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the POSIX groups (Python's regex engine doesn't support them anyway), but

```
r'[^[\x20-\x7E]]'
```

is definitely wrong (should be `r'[^\x20-\x7E]'`) *and* matches far more than

```
r'[\x00-\x1F\x7F]'
```

because the latter only considers ASCII characters whereas the former will also match anything above codepoint 126:

```
>>> r1 = re.compile(r'[^\x20-\x7E]')
>>> r2 = re.compile(r'[\x00-\x1F\x7F]')
>>> r1.match("ä")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='ä'>
>>> r2.match("ä")
>>>
```

To expand on my point above why your regex `r'[^[\x20-\x7E]]'` is faulty: it matches a letter that is neither an opening square bracket nor in the range between ASCII 20 and ASCII 126 (which already includes `[` anyway), and that is followed by a literal closing bracket:

```
>>> r1 = re.compile(r'[^[\x20-\x7E]]')
>>> r1.match("\x00")
>>> r1.match("\x00]")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='\x00]'>
```

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `[^\x20-\x7E]` and `[^[\x20-\x7E]]`? I'm not sure I understand the nesting of character sets.

Comment: @kevins: You can't nest character sets in Python. There are a few regex flavors that support character set *subtraction* like `[a-z-[aeiou]]` (which would match all letters except vowels), but Python is not among them.

Comment: Thanks again, really helpful. Think we could use a "Regex - From apprentice to guru" like there is for Python :)